# google.search.Search.apiary19431 is not a function

Tags: search

I have used google custom search in my site and it works well in chrome but I am facing problem in firefox It gives error like this.

**TypeError: google.search.Search.apiary19431 is not a function.**

Please friends help me to resolve this.

Comment: Please refer to this page https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/CYN9lFK46hk